# Document ready event solution in GWT

Tags: java, dom, gwt, dom-events

What is the best way to handle the moment when all widgets are first shown and finally sized in GWT? I need to handle only GWT part ready, not entire document ready...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either [Scheduler.scheduleFinally](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleFinally%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand%29)  or the [Scheduler.scheduleEntry](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleEntry%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand%29) function. They are run at the end of the event loop.

Also check out the gogole documentation on [delayed logic](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed.html)